# Open file from network drive

Tags: java, windows

I'm trying to create hyperlinks to open files from network drive G:

**This is part of my testing servlet:**

```
@WebServlet(name="fileHandler", urlPatterns={"/fileHandler/*"})
public class FileServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
  private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 10240; // 10KB.
  ...
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    String requestedFile = request.getPathInfo();
    ...
    File file = new File("G:/test_dir", URLDecoder.decode(requestedFile, "UTF-8")); // cesta se nacita v kazdem doGet
    String contentType = getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName());

    response.reset();
    response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    response.setContentType(contentType);
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");
    BufferedInputStream input = null;
    BufferedOutputStream output = null;

    try 
    {
      input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
      output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
      byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
      int length;
      while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) 
      {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
      }
    } 
    finally 
    { 
      close(output);
      close(input);
    }
  }
}
```

**My HTML component:**

```
<a href="fileHandler/test.txt">TEST FILE</a>
```

Network drive is mapped on application server as `G:\`

**Everything is working fine on my localhost** application server. I'm able to open file from local drive C: and even from the same network drive G:.

When I start the JSF application on real server, I'm able to open files from local drive only. **Not from G: drive**.

I've tried to simple `JAVA` application (to find if java instance has an access to network drive) and it works on both (server and dev.PC):

```
public class Test 
{
  static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    String path = "G:/test_dir/test.txt";
    File file = new File(path);
    System.err.println(file.exists() ? "OK" : "NOK");
  }
}
```

I've tried different URI schemes:

- `G:/test_dir`
- `G:\\test_dir`

And following doesn't work at all:

- `file://server/g:/test_dir`
- `///server/g:/test_dir`
- `\\\\server\\g\\test_dir` ---> in fact, this should work

Where should be a difference between my develop PC and application server?

**SOLUTION:**

I've found that [links to network drive doesn't work in standalone Tomcat, but works in Eclipse + Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987652/links-to-network-drive-doesnt-work-in-standalone-tomcat-but-works-in-eclipset), so I have to use complete URI:

- Case Eclipse + Tomcat: Path `G:/test_dir/test.txt` **works**
- Case Standalone Tomcat: Path `\\\\server\\g\\test_dir\\test.txt` **works**

Comment: Have you tried the simple test app on the server as well as your dev box?

Comment: Yes, it works on both

Comment: In that case, it might be work checking what the result of `URLDecoder.decode(requestedFile, "UTF-8")` is - maybe that's giving you a non-existant filename

Comment: I've tried to print the path and it seemed to be OK in all cases :-/ Java security seems to be OK, G: is mapped.. it's strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that [links to network drive doesn't work in standalone Tomcat, but works in Eclipse + Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987652/links-to-network-drive-doesnt-work-in-standalone-tomcat-but-works-in-eclipset), so I have to use complete URI:

- Case Eclipse + Tomcat: Path `G:/test_dir/test.txt` works
- Case Standalone Tomcat: Path `\\\\server\\g\\test_dir\\test.txt` works

Answer (score 1):

If you can debug your server and look at the logs, try this:

```
String requestedFile = request.getPathInfo();
log.debug('requestedFile='+requestedFile);
String decodedFilename = URLDecoder.decode(requestedFile, "UTF-8");
log.debug('decodedFilename='+decodedFilename);


File dir = new File("G:/test_dir");
log.debug('File g:/test_dir is a dir:'+dir.isDirectory());

File file = new File(dir, decodedFilename);
log.debug('requested file = '+file.getAbsolutePath());
log.debug('file exists = '+file.isFile());
```

If you do not have a logging framework set up, you can use `System.out.println()` instead of `log.debug()`, but that's not recommended for production use.

This won't solve your problem, but you'll be able to see what's going on.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it tomorrow!

Comment: I've found the difference. On my DEV-PC is it started on tomcat integrated to Eclipse. On the server is it deployed directly on Tomcat. When I try it to deploy it directly on tomcat on my DEV-PC, it also DOESN'T work. So it's seems to be another question..