# Links to network drive doesn't work in standalone Tomcat, but works in Eclipse+Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to create hyperlinks to open files from network drive `G:` (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970810/open-file-from-network-drive)). `G:` is mapped as network drive.

- When I deploy the WAR on Tomcat server integrated to Eclipse, **it works**.
- When I deploy it on the same but standalone Tomcat itself, **it doesn't work**

I've tried:

- Run Tomcat as `Domain Admin`, which has an access to the location, but **without success**.
- Run it as `Local user`, but check the box `Allow service to interact with desktop`. Also **without success**.

What's the difference in access between integrated Tomcat and Tomcat itself?

**SOLUTION:**

- Case Eclipse + Tomcat: Path `G:/test_dir/test.txt` **works**
- Case Standalone Tomcat: Path `\\\\server\\g\\test_dir\\test.txt` **works**

Comment: You need to post examples of what you re doing.

Comment: I've write it to the previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970810/open-file-from-network-drive), but I've found, that it seems not to be problem of URI or method, but in difference between tomcat integrated to Eclipse or not.. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

- Case Eclipse + Tomcat: Path `G:/test_dir/test.txt` works
- Case Standalone Tomcat: Path `\\\\server\\g\\test_dir\\test.txt` works

Comment: Could you find a reason for this? Or, make Standalone Tomcat work for other paths as well?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you cannot access shared network drive because account that runs standalone Tomcat does not have enough privileges.

I had a similar issue (running Tomcat as a Windows service) that couldn't access shared network drive because service was running with local admin account that didn't have access to shared network drive.

Since you are on Windows, try running Tomcat as a domain user that has access to a network drive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried it (as you can find in my post), but it doesn't work